# Is it possible to drill-down twice with jvectormap?

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

Is it possible to drill-down twice? The [drill-down example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/drill-down/) shows US drill-down to each state. Is it possible to drill-down from the world map to the US map, and then drill-down again to one of the states?